# Only show windows 7 Preview Pane (in explorer) when the file has a preview

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, preview

I use the preview pane often, especially with pdfs. But when selecting folders or files which don't have previews, or not even selecting anything, the preview pane stays, it's quite big, and I use lots when I have the explorer window maximised on my 1920x1080 monitor in this case it takes up about half my screen, but when I use explorer in a smaller window the preview pane shrinks the cneter folder pane and stays half the size of the window.

Is there anyway to only show the preview pane when the file has a preview and then hide it again when the file doesn't or not file is selected.
 (btw, please don't say about alternate file browsers, as they all look ugly and complicated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your explorer window: look at the top right hand side in the toolbar area: there is a ? icon that provides "help".
Immediately located to the left of this icon is a square box type icon. Click on this icon to hide the preview pane.

Keep this clicked on hide until you come across a folder with PDF's, at this point you can click on it again to show it.

Comment: Yes I'm well aware of that, I want it to do it automatically, for example it can't preview DLL files so it should hide the preview pane when I select a DLL.